# Typescript Reactjs Jest/Enzyme Error - 'Type 'any[]' is missing the following properties...'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, enzyme

```
let wrapper;
const setState = jest.fn();
const useStateSpy = jest.spyOn(React, "useState")
useStateSpy.mockImplementation((init) => [init, setState]);

beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = Enzyme.mount(Enzyme.shallow(<AddOption/>).get(0))
});

afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
});
```

I am trying to mock state however for this line -

```
useStateSpy.mockImplementation((init) => [init, setState]);
```

I am getting the error:

```
Type 'any[]' is missing the following properties from type '[unknown, Dispatch<unknown>]': 0, 1ts(2739)
```

I am unsure as to how to fix this error and haven't been able to find much online in relation to fixing an error like this for this particular use case.

Comment: Why do you use both mount and shallow to render AddOption?

Comment: @Rostyslav I am following a guide online to write a test for a form component so I am honestly not too sure... I am new to react tests but a lot of examples online are not using typescript also, as i am - https://dev.to/austinbh/testing-forms-in-react-using-enzyme-and-jest-2983

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my perspective it is kind of a hack but you can try this

```
...
const init = {}; // or anything you want to be the initial state
useStateSpy.mockImplementation(() => [init, setState] as any);
...
```

OR

```
...
const init = {}; // or anything you want to be the initial state
useStateSpy.mockReturnValue([init, setState] as any);
...
```

Comment: Giving error - Argument of type '(init: any) => any[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '() => [unknown, Dispatch<unknown>]'

Comment: @monkeys73 there should be an indication of a line where the error occurs. Can you, please, provide the code of the test with that line? and also for AddOption?

Comment: @monkeys73 happy to help :) Btw, if you find my answer useful, please, accept it and give an upvote so the issue can be considered as closed